# Запятая в предложении: "Ну ничего себе у тебя запросы!"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос. Заставил задуматься. Сперва я подумал, что "ничего себе" - вводная конструкция, придающая эмоциональную окраску, но, как обособил её, смысл изменился, поэтому, подумав, я сделал вывод, что "ничего себе" синонимично слову "большие", следовательно, обособлять не надо.

Comment: Хорошо заменяется на частицу "И" - Ну у тебя и запросы!